# How can i reduce the image rotation quality loss?

Tags: c#

This is my Form1 code for rotating and its working the image i can rotate it by 360 degrees.
The problem is while rotating the image is losing a lot of quality.

I tried to use some codec there but im not sure how to implent it with my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace AnimatedGifEditor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        ImageCodecInfo ici = null; 
        Image myImage;
        AnimatedGif myGif;
        Bitmap bitmap;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myImage = Image.FromFile(@"D:\fananimation.gif");
            myGif = new AnimatedGif(@"D:\fananimation.gif");
            for (int i = 0; i < myGif.Images.Count; i++)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = myGif.Images[3].Image;
                bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
               // pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
            }

            trackBar1.Maximum = 360;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap bmp, float angle)
        {
            Bitmap rotatedImage = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedImage))
            {
                g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2); //set the rotation point as the center into the matrix
                g.RotateTransform(angle); //rotate
                g.TranslateTransform(-bmp.Width / 2, -bmp.Height / 2); //restore rotation point into the matrix
                g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0)); //draw the image on the new bitmap
            }

            return rotatedImage;
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
                    ici = codec;
            }

            EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100);



            pictureBox1.Image = RotateImage(bitmap, trackBar1.Value);
        }


    }
}
```

In the top of the Form i added:

```
ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
ImageCodecInfo ici = null;
```

And inside the scrol event i added:

```
foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
                {
                    if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
                        ici = codec;
                }

                EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100);
```

But i never use this encoding code. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your `RotateImage` you should be setting the `Graphics` object interpolation mode to high quality:

```
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
```

Another thing which is unrelated to your question, is that your are not disposing the previous image properly.

You should start your `RotateImage` method with:

```
if (rotatedImage != null) rotatedImage.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

dummy code:

Specifies a 180-degree clockwise rotation without flipping.

```
public static Image RotateImage(Image image)
        {
            image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            return image;
        }
```